# C# equivalent of Scala Promise

Tags: c#, scala, promise, task, future

In scala there are `Promises` and `Futures`. With `Promise` I can control when `Future` completes, i.e.

```
val p = Promise[Int]()
val fut: Future[Int] = p.future // I already have a running Future here

// here I can do whatever I want and when I decide Future should complete, I can simply say
p success 7
// and fut is now completed with value 7
```

How can I achieve similar results with C# `Task` API? I couldn't find anything equivalent in docs.

I want to use this in a test, mocked object returns such `Task` and then I check if some condition holds before task completes, then complete it and check another condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
void Main()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    tcs.SetResult(true);
    Console.WriteLine(tcs.Task.IsCompleted); // prints true.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need are Tasks. You can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx).

```
 Task<int> futureB = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => F1(a));
  int c = F2(a); 
  int d = F3(c); 
  int f = F4(futureB.Result, d);
  return f;
```

You can use try/catch to help you manage possible error.
To force the output value you can use `TaskCompletionSource` as mentioned above by another user.

Comment: I am aware of Tasks, I even have that stated in my question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12239926)

Comment: I elaborated the answer a bit more. Thanks for the feedback @PieterVandenheede

Answer (score 0):

#### It's `TaskCompletionSource`

Like Yuval said, `TaskCompletionSource` is a Promise and a `Task` is a `Future` but note that in C# *you should rarely use `TaskCompletionSource`*.

The reason is that `TaskCompletionSource` is used to convert a non-task API to a task based one. In C#, almost all APIs are already `Task`-returning.

So while they're similar - in C# you rarely need `TaskCompletionSource` (where `Promise` in scala is common).

### You're probably looking for [`FromResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to create a mock API with tasks you don't want TaskCompletionSource, you want `FromResult` which creates a completed task based on a value:

```
void Fn()
{
    var task = Task.FromResult(true);
    Console.WriteLine(task.IsCompleted); // prints true.
    Console.WriteLine(task.Result); // prints true. a ""blocking"" API
}
```

Comment: From what I encountered till now, same what you say for c# holds for scala, the usage of Promise is the same and you mostly use Futures. If you look back to my question, I said that I need a not completed task and decide when it completes, this is not a common usage but I need this for my test.

Comment: @Łukasz hopefully, but in Scala futures are common but not _everywhere_, you have lots of places using Java APIs and callback APIs you need to convert - in C# _every single API_ created in the last few years returns tasks including the big base class library. Also note in C# you should use tasks with `async/await` most of the time.

Comment: @Łukasz even then, you have `Task.` utility methods for most stuff. When you say it's asynchronous - is it asynchronous on IO? You also have `Task.Run` if it's just tests where you can block and (probably, usually) runs on another thread.

Comment: I always use `Task.FromResult` in my tests but this one is different and does the following: I'm testing if my viewmodel would disable a `Command` for the time when `Task` runs and enable back when it's done. How can I test that in some other way?

Comment: I think `Task.FromResult` is most likely what he doesn't want. He wants to hand out a `Task` and decide when it's complete.